# How to load a profile from within IPython shell?

Tags: configuration, ipython

For reasons explained in this [Celery-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657701/how-to-start-celery-shell-with-any-ipython-profile-for-custom-configuration), I want to be able to load or change IPython profiles **from within the interactive shell** via a magic command or programmatically. I cannot find any way to set the profile (`get_ipython().profile` only seems to retrieve the current one).

I'm using IPython `2.3.1`.